# What event fires after a form is initially loaded?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm particularly interested in an event I can hook into that fires after the form is loaded so I can initialize the fields, etc., in the controller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no event, but you could add a `initialize` method, which is invoked by the `FXMLLoader` after the content is created and fields are injected to the controller instance:

```
public MyController {

    @FXML
    private Node someNode;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("someNode: " + someNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo. I love SO.

Comment: @nicomp You should mark this answer as correct if it answers the question you posted.